# Is it possible to change the number of test methods in JUNIT?

Tags: java, html, junit

I have a Testsuite with a number of Testcases. Now each test case contains a variable number of smaller tests. The number of these smaller tests vary though. I need the JUnit GUI to present if each smaller tests works underneath the Testcase. Is this possible? Using different @Test methods gives me the structure I want but I cannot dynamically change the number of these @Test methods neccessary for the Testcases. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look to JUnit parametrized test ?

And now using @Parameters annotation you can iterate over your data and change the name of each test like this :

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class JunitTest {

     private int number;

     public JunitTest(int number) {
        this.number = number;
     }

     @Parameters(name = "namestring")
     public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
       Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 } };
       return Arrays.asList(data);
     }

     @Test
     public void simpleTest() {
       System.out.println("Parameterized Number is : " + number);
     }
}
```

**namestring** is a string, which can have the following special placeholders:

- {index} - the index of this set of arguments. The default namestring is {index}.
- {0} - the first parameter value from this invocation of
  the test.
- {1} - the second parameter value

and so on

Comment: Sure I did I am using a parameterized Test which runs all my Testclasses. The Problem: each Testclass contains a few small tests. I would like these tests to show up in the JUNIT GUI under the name of the Testclass. these smaller tests are always different therefore its not possible to set the number of methods neede beforehand..